# Conditional rendering for Datetime string in Javascript

Tags: javascript, date, datetime

I have defined an array of dates in Javascript like this:

```
dates: [
            {id: 1, date: new Date(2020, 1, 4,  9, 0)},
            {id: 2, date: new Date(2020, 30, 4,  9, 0)},
            {id: 3, date: new Date(2020, 1, 5,  9, 0)},
            {id: 4, date: new Date(2020, 2, 3,  9, 0)},
            {id: 5, date: new Date(2020, 5, 5,  9, 0)},
       ]
```

I would like to do conditional rendering for everything before 12 PM and after 12 PM

```
if (is after 12pm) {
   return function;
} else {
   return function;
}
```

Is there any way I can check the time of a date string? Or is there a better way to define dates and then check the date time?

Comment: `new Date(2020, 1, 4,  9, 0)` creates a Date object or instance, not a string. ;-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've written a script which goes through the whole array and outputs to the console whether each date is before 12 or not.

Note that I've changed a few values in the array to have a range of dates, some before 12, some after 12, and one at 12 exactly.

```js
dates = [
  {id: 1, date: new Date(2020, 1, 4,  13, 0)},
  {id: 2, date: new Date(2020, 30, 4,  9, 0)},
  {id: 3, date: new Date(2020, 1, 5,  12, 0)},
  {id: 4, date: new Date(2020, 2, 3,  22, 0)},
  {id: 5, date: new Date(2020, 5, 5,  9, 0)},
]

for (var i = 0; i < dates.length; i++) {
  
  if (dates[i].date.getHours() < 12) {
    console.log('Before 12.');
  } else {
    console.log('Not before 12.');
  }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have created a object with two keys id (a number) and date (a string), to create a date you can use Date Class of java Script:
You can use Date.prototype.getHours() function it returns the hour (0–23) in the specified date according to local time and then check the value:

```
Date.prototype.getHours()
```

visit this for details:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getHours

Answer (score 0):

Use the momentjs library.

```
var moment = require('moment');

var dates = [
        {id: 1, date: new Date(2020, 1, 4,  9, 0)},
        {id: 2, date: new Date(2020, 30, 4,  9, 0)},
        {id: 3, date: new Date(2020, 1, 5,  9, 0)},
        {id: 4, date: new Date(2020, 2, 3,  9, 0)},
        {id: 5, date: new Date(2020, 5, 5,  9, 0)},
   ]

for(let i = 0; i < dates.length; i++){
  console.log(moment(this.dates[i].date).locale('en').format('hh'));
}
```